# How to get list of available custom template name using powershell script

Tags: powershell, site-collection, sub-site

I want to create subsite using custom template. how can get list of activated custom template name using powershell script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have answered for the same kind of query , Please find below the detail to get the available custom templates and create a sub-site based on that .

This can be achieved using power shell and CSOM by following below steps .

Once the custom template is uploaded into the solution gallery of the site collection execute the below commands in Powershell:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web ServerExtensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web ServerExtensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

$Site = "SiteCollectionURL"
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($Site)
```

## List Custom Templates

```
$Templates = $Context.Site.GetWebTemplates("1033","0")
$Context.Load($Templates)
$Context.ExecuteQuery()
$Templates | Where {$_.Name -like "*{*" } | Select Name, Description
```

This will list out all the custom templates available in the gallery.

And execute the below commands to create the subsite using the custom template:

## Create Sub-Web using the Custom Template

```
$WCI = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WebCreationInformation
$WCI.WebTemplate = "{516EB07D-8711-4B9F-A3AD-097B28C5CDDF}#MyCustomTemplate"
$WCI.Description = "MyNewSubSite"
$WCI.Title = "MyNewSubSite"
$WCI.Url = "MyNewSubSite"
$WCI.Language = "1033"
$SubWeb = $Context.Web.Webs.Add($WCI)
$Context.ExecuteQuery().
```

Comment: when i'm creating subsite using custom template I got this error **Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The site template
requires that the Feature {ce503d26-5ac4-4af9-be10-e167610d7bd1} be installed
in the farm or site collection."**

Comment: Please make sure that the solution for the custom template is activated . other thing try to get the feature using get-spfeature -identity {guid} and check the results.   Try to enable this feature using **Enable-SPFeature -identity "MyCustom" -URL http://somesite**

Comment: When I run It returns another error **ca18553c-d520-4e1d-8fd4-e57ccf24aa36 in scope Local farm.**

Comment: can you post the entire error thrown ??

Comment: Its not a web template it is a site template

Comment: I'm having somesite.wsp as site template and I Added and activated the site template  to the solution gallery with the below script **Add-SPUserSolution -LiteralPath C:\Users\admin\Desktop\somesite.wsp -Site http://<sitename>/sites/<sitecollection>/<subsite>

Install-SPUserSolution -Identity somesite.wsp -Site http://<sitename>/sites/<sitecollection>/<subsite>**  .the above script successfully activated the site template. after that I follow above answer, It gives custom site template name and feature Id .then I try to create subsite with custom template It gives error like below.

Comment: **Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "The site template
requires that the Feature {ce503d26-5ac4-4af9-be10-e167610d7bd1} be installed
in the farm or site collection."
At line:1 char:1
+ $Context.ExecuteQuery()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ServerException
**

Comment: It means some of the feature already activated while taking the site template i.e in the existing site is missing in the current site , so please make sure that before taking the site template deactivating the features which are all dependent on other custom wsp.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48652/discussion-between-jeeva-jeyapaul-and-esaki).

Answer (score 4):

This should help

```
$web = get-spweb http://intranet
$template = $web.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1033)
```

To create a new subsite, based off of a custom web template, you can use the following script

```
$web = get-spweb http://intranet
$template = $web.GetAvailableWebTemplates(1033) | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "My Custom Template Name"}
New-SPWeb -Url "http://intranet/site1" -Name "Site 1" –Template $template
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code, will give you a list of all available templates. Using this, you can find out the custom template name as well as its ID

```
function Get-SPWebTemplateWithId 
{ 
     $templates = Get-SPWebTemplate | Sort-Object "Name" 
     $templates | ForEach-Object { 
    $templateValues = @{ 
     "Title" = $_.Title 
     "Name" = $_.Name 
     "ID" = $_.ID 
     "Custom" = $_.Custom 
     "LocaleId" = $_.LocaleId 
      }

New-Object PSObject -Property $templateValues | Select @("Name","Title","LocaleId","Custom","ID") 
      } 
}

Get-SPWebTemplateWithId | Format-Table
```

Comment: It shows only default templates