# Template for Site creation fails when scheduled works from command prompt

Tags: site, template, scheduled-tasks

I've got a .NET core application that run fine from a command prompt that creates SharePoint Sites and adds content types from templates. When I schedule it to run via Windows Scheduled Tasks with the same account it fails with the following error:

Error applying client template: The Provisioning Template URI "MyTemplate.xml" is not valid.

The "client template" is the site collection template

What would cause it to not run properly when scheduled?

Comment: Is this office 365 or on premise?

Comment: @Andrew Office 365 I believe as I'm still getting up to speed on all things SharePoint. The URL is CompanyName.SharePoint.com/bla/bla/bla

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not finding the file because the scheduled task is not looking in the folder you expect it to.

Comment: Derek, are you saying it is all related to Scheduled Tasks and not SharePoint? If so can you elaborate? The custom templates for site creation are in a sub directory relative to where the .exe is located

Comment: Derek Set me on the right path. Check out this SO post to set directory/.folder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476149/file-not-found-using-task-scheduler

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out this link: [How to get list of available custom template name using powershell script](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/199804/how-to-get-list-of-available-custom-template-name-using-powershell-script)

If the template you are using is not one of the templates that are used by default  it may cause some issues when calling on the template.

I use [pnp PowerShell](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/sharepoint/sharepoint-pnp/sharepoint-pnp-cmdlets?view=sharepoint-ps) tools to find info about the available templates and their names. Hope this helps.